Set cookie in php
I have a php file add_cookie.php that is set up like so:
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$cookie_name = "testCookie";
$cookie_value = "cookieValue";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day

echo "Headers sent by the server:<br>";
print_r(headers_list());

As far as I understand, the website does send the headers since the headers_list() returns: Array ( [0] => Set-Cookie: testCookie=cookieValue; expires=Thu, 29-Aug-2024 21:08:20 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/ ) ande adding a location header does also redirect to another page, but the cookie header seems to be ignored by the browser as it is nowhere to be found. Why does that happen?
The website is on WordPress, but I don't want to import anything in this file. I am aware of add_action('init', ...).

@luk2302 Why do you think it's the wrong format? The documentation for setcookie() says it's a Unix timestamp, not a Date object.

If you look at the header in the browser's DevTools, do you see the Set-Cookie header?

I've just tried your script and got the cookie set in the browser so are you able to give a bit more detail about how the script is being called? e.g. direct via URL, iframe, javascript

@Barmar No, but I can see the location header if I send one though

@Mark I am just calling the script directly from Chrome like https://example.com/my_folder/add_cookie.php .  The issue may be somewhere in WordPress, but isn't it supposed to not be loaded when the php file is run directly? I certainly don't have any WordPress functions defined.

The issue may be with cloudflare, but if they are not allowing cookies, then how am I able to set them with 'init' hook?

I don't think the issue can be with Wordpress because you are loading the script directly and not importing any of Wordpress, besides I have also tried it in a Wordpress site and it works fine. I don't have any experience with Cloudflare so cannot help there but it can be configured to remove Cookies: https://developers.cloudflare.com/rules/transform/request-header-modification/#:~:text=Configuring%20a%20rule%20that%20removes,HTTP%20request%20header%20is%20removed.
